# Is my system compromised or vulnerable to attacks

Tags: security

I ran `netstat -lntup` with the network connected. Recently one of my friends exploited my linux system using backtrack so I had to format it. Now I want to know whether I'm still being exploited or exposed and how to prevent being hacked and how to close open ports[image: netstat -lntup]

Answer (score 2):

Well for starters you should have posted which *nix are you using. On which version? What services are being run on your machine?

As for `Recently one of my friends exploited my linux system using backtrack so I had to format it.` I'm quite at a loss of words. Frankly I'm not sure why do you think that reinstalling your system just as it was will solve the original problem you had. (Because it most probably won't.)
Also: how do you know he *did indeed* exploit your machine? Because he claimed so? Did you experience anything that wasn't supposed to happen?

As for your screenshot (you should have pasted terminal output as it's quite hard to identify which line starts and ends where), I can see that you are running a file server ([SAMBA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samba_%28software%29)) and a print server ([CUPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUPS)) that is publicly accessible. (Not taking into account that you might have some firewall rules.)
I'm not sure if you really want that (probably not) and as such I'd fix them up.

As for the future if you intend to ask questions like these keep in mind that we will need a lot more info than what you gave.
I.e.:
The full outputs of `uname -a`; `ifconfig -a`; `netstat -nlp`; `iptables -L`;
 `service --status-all`; and probably a few more.

Comment: i used ubuntu 13.10 & yes my friend could tell what i was browsing and we were not in the same networks. Why wont a clean installation remove the exploit...can you please explain and the possible remedies

Answer (score 0):

> Is my system compromised
>
> or vulnerable to attacks

Any powered-on system is vulnerable to attacks of some nature.  There are many security models ranging from "airgap required between Internet and the LAN this system is on" to "trust anything on your LAN" to "full zerotrust - assume everything is already compromised."

> Now I want to know whether I'm still being exploited

To absolutely prevent traffic from coming in an port, you need to block it using `iptables`.

An exploited system is typically sending or receiving network traffic it shouldn't.  You can't 100% reliably say that *isn't* happening from within a system you think is compromised, but you might be able to find evidence that it *is* from within that system.

Look into tools like `iftop` and such, but if you don't know what your system's "baseline" network activity is, you don't have anything to compare against.

Note that there are many ways to exploit a system besides open ports.

> or exposed

Do not run services you don't need.  Looking at your `netstat` above, do you need CUPS running?  Do you need Samba running (`smbd`)?  Do you need Avahi running?

FWIW the above looks like a typical default install of some desktop distribution.  It doesn't look unusual but a `netstat` is really only the tip of the iceberg.  Remove what you don't use if you are concerned about security.

> and how to prevent being hacked

This is a complex subject which experts dedicate their lives to, but here's some general things as a start to further research on your part:

- Block everything but ports you are actually going to run stuff on with `iptables`.
- Do not run or install unnecessary software.
- Choose good passwords.  Change them periodically.
- Do not run as root unless needed.  Minimize time you spend as root.
- Look into adding static ARP entries for known systems on your network.
- If you can use a static IP and not rely on DHCP to configure your network, do it.
- Disable IPv6 if you don't use it.  If you happen to be able to run IPv6 only you should.
- Use full disk encryption if you can.
- Lock your system when you walk away from it.
- Shut down your system when you are not using it.
- Apply security updates as soon as you can.